# Rmarkdown - two datatables next to each other

Tags: r, r-markdown, datatables-1.10

I would like to show two datatables next to each other in Rmarkdown.

````
```{r , echo = FALSE}
library(DT)
datatable(dt1)
datatable(dt2)
```
````

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612453/how-to-make-2-datatables-to-show-next-to-each-other-in-a-page) post shows how it could be done with CSS, but I don't know CSS enough to make it happen.

Comment: This might help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753897/2-column-section-in-r-markdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help get you started:

````
<div style="width: 100%;">

<div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
```{r , echo = FALSE}
library(DT)
dt1 = mtcars[1:5,1:3]
dt2 = dt1
datatable(dt1)
```
</div>

<div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
 ```{r , echo = FALSE}
datatable(dt2)
```
</div>
````

Comment: I used this one. Thank you